# IDA Python call func from idb names with specific arguments

Tags: idapython

I'm new in IDA Python, so the question is hard for me. I didn't find any solution in google, so I have to ask for the help there. During code analysis I found decryption function. There are about 1000 calls of this function with different arguments. The function takes one argument - encrypted string, which address is moved to eax before the calling.
I'd like to write script for running the function for all encrypted strings. I find address of the function using idc.LocByName. Then I found all references to this function (using idautils.CodeRefsTo(addr, 1)). Now I to find the function's argument for each reference and call the function with this argument. 
Could you please advise the way I can do it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general you have 3 possibilities:

1 - Recover arguments statically and use [AppCall](https://hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/tutorials/debugging_appcall.pdf) either with IDC or IDAPython in debug session

2 - Rewrite decryption function in python, [recover arguments statically](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/11332/automating-a-decryption-function-call-in-ida-python) and run the recovered function on each occurrence.

3 - Use something like [PyEmu](https://github.com/codypierce/pyemu) for running functions.

Usually I find variant 2 easier then others.

Comment: Thanks. Variant two looks like solution. I'll try to implement it.