# IDA rename argument in all xrefs to function

Tags: ida, idapython

I have a function of the format:

```
sub_ABCDEF(&global, "stringName", unimportantValue)

push    offset string
mov     ecx, offset global
call    sub_410010
```

That is called in several places, each varying the &global and string location.

I am wondering if it's possible in IDAPython to bulk rename all the &global's to the string value.

I used XrefsTo(410010, 0) to obtain a list of places the function is called from, but I am unsure how to get the parameters it was called with.

Comment: That's not exact duplicate, but I answered a similar question once: https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/11332/automating-a-decryption-function-call-in-ida-python . Actually you need to recover arguments, the script there show how to do it.